# gtk3 motionNotifyEvent doesn't work when button is depressed

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, gtk2hs

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Graphics.UI.Gtk

main :: IO ()
main = do
    initGUI
    window <- windowNew
    canvas <- drawingAreaNew

    widgetAddEvents canvas [Button1MotionMask]

    canvas `on` motionNotifyEvent $ do
        c <- eventCoordinates
        liftIO $ print c
        return False

    containerAdd window canvas
    widgetShowAll window
    mainGUI
```

In the code above, I am trying to handle a 'mouse drag' on a `GtkDrawingArea`, where the left mouse button is depressed. However, nothing is printed, indicating that the event is never firing. Even stranger, when I change `Button1MotionMask` to `PointerMotionMask`, the event fires when I move my mouse normally (as expected), but not when I move the mouse while depressing the left mouse button. What is going on here? I am using the `gtk3-0.14.8` package on Windows 10.

**EDIT:** I should probably be a bit clearer about my problem. When I hold the left mouse button down while moving the mouse, `motionNotifyEvent`does not fire. This does not depend on whether I have added `PointerMotionMask` or `Button1MotionMask`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation, but it turns out that you also need to enable `ButtonPressMask` to recieve *any* event with the mouse button pressed - including motion events which occur when the button is pressed down. This results in the paradoxical behaviour where enabling only `Button1MotionMask` results in no events being received unless you also enable `ButtonPressMask`. I finally figured this out after discovering the gtk-demo sample application - it's very useful for learning GTK!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, C documentation on motion-notify-event says

> To receive this signal, the GdkWindow associated to the widget needs to enable the GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK mask

Enabling only GDK_BUTTON1_MOTION_MASK doesn't work for me too. 
Fortunately, GdkEventMotion has field `state`, where you can check whether button1 is pressed or not.